# JqGrid - How to execute custom functionality for each grid of application on jqGridInitGrid event

Tags: jqgrid

In our application we have more than 100 grids and we need to display help button on Title bar of grid, for that I have created a plugin using

```
$.jgrid.extend({    
    EnableHelpButton: function(value) {
        var $t = this;
        ...............;
    }
    });
```

Currently, I go to each .html page of grid and need to call the EnableHelpButton as shown in below code.

-----------------Index1.html-------------------------

```
$("#TestGrid1").bind("jqGridInitGrid", function () {
            $(this).EnableHelpButton(true);
        });
```

-----------------Index2.html-------------------------

```
$("#TestGrid2").bind("jqGridInitGrid", function () {
            $(this).EnableHelpButton(true);
        });
```

How I can create a generic way to call this EnableHelpButton on jqGridInitGrid events of each grid. It should write once on single place and it should work for each grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to have some *specific* call of your custom function on every page. One way will be to define you plugin so

```js
$.jgrid.extend({    
    EnableHelpButton: function(value) {
        var $t = this;
        ...............;
    },
    myInit: function () {
        return this.each(function () {
            $(this).bind("jqGridInitGrid", function ({
                $(this).EnableHelpButton(true);
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Even in the case you need to include `.jqGrid("myInit")` call **on every** page. You can make the call of `myInit` *before* the `<table>` is converted to grid. For example instead of

```js
$("#grid").jqGrid({
    ... // parameter used to create jqGrid
});
```

you will be use now

```js
$("#grid").jqGrid("myInit").jqGrid({
    ... // parameter used to create jqGrid
});
```

Only if you *never* use `onInitGrid` **callback** in any your grids you can use the callback instead of `jqGridInitGrid`. In the case you need just define the callback in some JavaScript code which you included in every your page:

```js
$.extend(true, $.jgrid.defaults, {
    onInitGrid: function () {
        $(this).EnableHelpButton(true);
    }
});
```

In the way you will set default implementation of `onInitGrid` for every grid.

Thus the definition of common initialization inside of `onInitGrid` callback produces the shortest implementation, but have restriction that you shouldn't use the callback in no of your grids. Alternatively you defines the method `myInit` which makes all bindings add you can add `.jqGrid("myInit")` on every your grids. The last approach will work for every jqGrid.

Comment: Thank you Oleg, provided solution work perfectly and meet the requirement.